# Netbeans macro command for /* */ comment block

Tags: php, netbeans, macros

I am using Netbeans 6.8 and trying to create a custom PHP comment code block macro with the /* */ style and not the usual double slash.

So far with googling and asking in PHPUGPH, I got this macro code (tools->options->editor->macros):

```
copy-to-clipboard delete-previous "/*" paste-from-clipboard "*/"
```

You must first highlight the code and press the shortcut key combination to make a comment block.

My problem now is I don't know the macro code to uncomment a PHP block.
I found some code but I can't make it work.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old (a little over a year), but I found this while looking for useful macros for netbeans and noticed it was still unanswered. I've figured out a solution if you're still interested. I know I'll be using it from now on, thanks for the idea :)

```
selection-forward
selection-forward
copy-to-clipboard
remove-line
paste-from-clipboard
delete-previous
delete-previous
insert-break
```

Edit: BTW, I'm using 7.0.1, but I believe this should still work in 6.8

Answer (score 3):

this macro worked for me (similar to dreamweaver php block comment).

added to options > editor > macros

```
cut-to-clipboard "<?php /*" paste-from-clipboard "*/ ?>"
```

i set the keyboard shortcut to shift+option+cmd+c (mac)

Comment: Good answer. I made a small change on this. Removed `<?php` and `?>` portions of this code. It is adding `php` tag to the code section

Answer (score 1):

Here is one of the simple solution for doing this

Just create your macro and then put this code in macro

copy-to-clipboard
" " paste-from-clipboard ""

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure about macros, but I know Netbeans has a really useful comment and uncomment buttons for a block of code. Simply highlight all the code you want to comment or uncomment and click one of the 2 buttons. (one button for commenting, the other for uncommenting)

[image]

Comment: It will add a slash comment and not a block comment ---> /* */