# how do I comment out php code in netbeans 7.1

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7

If i want to comment out php code in netbeans i have to do it manually as i haven't found a way of doing it from a netbeans command ?

so if i have this code example:

```
<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>
```

I would manual type:

```
<?php /*<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?> */?>
```

Using the insert comment button only seems to include // 0r

```
<!-- --> which does not comment out php code ?
```

in dreamweaver you also have the option of php comment , is this function available in netbeans ?

Many thanks

Comment: See if the answer given here would work for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131502/php-netbeans-macro-command-for-comment-block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server will interpret the php file before hand, `<!-- -->` is used to comment once the php is converted to HTML.
So you may use :

```
<?php /*bloginfo('template_url')*/ ?>
```

Which only comment the php code and so won't be executed on php compilation